# How do I find neighbours (horizontal, vertical, diagonal) of a specific integer within a grid made of lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, grid

If I have a grid made of lists that comprise the rows, how can I find the items that are in contact (either to its left or right in the same row, one above or below in the same column, or touching it diagonally)? Let's say the grid looks like this:

```
[[1, 5000, 10000]
 [2500, 255, 230]
 [12500, 4250, 1]]
```

I want to find the integers in the grid that are in contact with the '1's (bottom right, top left). Using list comprehension is ideal, but I'm just not sure how to order the language required of this task. I want to convert the 1s to the average value of its direct neighbours with something like:

```
for row in grid:
    for item in row:
        if item == 0:
            item = neighbourAverage
```

Getting that neighbourAverage variable is my problem, just because I'm not sure how to navigate to specific spots and figure out whether it's 'touching' the object in question. I also want to develop code that works for a grid of any size.

Any advice is much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have the right idea just add some boundary checks in yiur loop where the `x` and `y` coordinates correspond to the list length and second dimension length respectively. So that `x = grid.len()` and `y = row.len()` then with `+/-1` on each vector add a bounds check to not exceed x/y and not drop below 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm understanding how it would theoretically work, but due to my lack of understanding of how the language works, I'm having trouble conceptualizing how it would within the code. Using row.len() I can give the grid x and y max that match the length of those lists, but how would make it work so that any item could be assigned those values, and from there, everything around it be checked and accepted as a neighbour or not? Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: I mean if you conceptualize the vector as a euclidian distance heuristic you can capture all 8 surrounding vectors with a distance of plus or minus one. So `x = x + 1` is the neighboring vector to your right and `x = x - 1` is the neighboring vector to your left and the same proposition for y coordinates. The `x = x + 1` `y = y + 1` combination gives you top right corners etc. There are basically 8 touching vectors in each iterarion of your loop.